# Change google map center in google map v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm changing a marker position to somewhere else in google map in runtime. It works nicely.

I also want to set the map center position to that latlon. But map becomes gray when i change the center latlon. Here is my code-

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.780691190209286, 80.41932580000002);
var currentMarker = myMarkers[0];
currentMarker.setPosition(myLatlng);
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatlng);
myMap.setCenter(center);
google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');
myMap.setZoom(myMap.getZoom());
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatlng);
```

`LatLng()` is specified as `LatLng(lat:number, lng:number, noWrap?:boolean)` so you cannot provide another latlng object to initialize it.

You can just call:

```
myMap.setCenter(myLatlng);
```

Comment: Yeap, that line is wrong. Now it works. thanks Anto.